# Call new activity and destroy current one

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have three activities: A, B and C.

A is an intent to B and B is an intent to C,

When I finish the operation in C, I want to *destroy* C and go back to A, not B.

I've tried this:

```java
finish();
B b = new B();
b.finish();
```

in C, doesn't work; And

```java
finish();
B b = new B();
b.onDestroy();
```

in C, it results in a `NullPointerException`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: in acticity A dont call finish()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this,ToActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

From the documentation about **[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)**:

> **[FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)**  If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack
>
> **[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)**  If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.

Comment: use it where?. u mean setFlags method? ok I will check that out

Comment: I figured that out with a another way ,anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that:

First: add [android:noHistory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) attribute to your B activity in the manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name=".A"/>
<activity android:name=".B" android:noHistory="true"/> <!-- This attribute will prevent adding activity to activity stack-->
<activity android:name=".C"/>
```

Second: call finish just after you start new activity

```
// Put this code in your B activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish() // This will finish current activity (activity B in your case) and activity stack will only contain A activity
```

Third: put flags [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) in your C activity intent

```
// Put this code in your B activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); // This will exclude current activity (activity B in your case) from activity stack
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

On completing your operation, you can call an intent to get you to the Activity you want like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityA.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: He don't want to recreate an Activity, he want to go directly to A he just have to not finish the A activity

Answer (score 0):

Call the activity from an `Intent` and then call `finish()`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(C.this, A.class));
finish();
```

`finish()` will remove activity from back stack and the new activity would be started be the `startActivity()` method.